# Ranges of floating point in C programming language

Tags: c, types, floating-point, precision

According to [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm), the FLOAT data type in C ranges from 1.2E-38 to 3.4E+38 and has 6 decimal places of precision.

However, in my point of view, the value 1.2E-38 requires much more that 6 decimal places of precision for being represented.

What is wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Have you ever wondered what the “floating” in “floating-point” meant? It means you can represent 1.2e-38 with 6 decimal places of precision. This said, do not try to think in decimal about binary floating-point.

Comment: 1.2 is two decimal digits. The exponent has nothing to do with it. [See this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Scientific_notation). [This link may also be useful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32).

Comment: How many digits did it just take you to represent 1.2E-38 when you were typing this up?

Comment: 0.000000000000000000012 has 21 decimal places, and 2 decimal places *of precision*.

Comment: stop thinking decimal, it is a binary format not a decimal format.  think of how many bits of mantissa not decimal digits.

Comment: The words "precision", and "range" all have specific technical meanings.

Answer (score 4):

Precision in floating point refers to the number of *leading significant* digits.

For common `float`, it can be considered to have [at least 6 decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49961587/2410359) digits of significance.

---

Recall that floating point numbers are distributed logarithmically.  There are about as many different FP number from 0.1 to 0.2 as between 10 to 20 as between 0.000001 to 0.000002 as between 1,000,000 to 2,000,000.

Notice that the digits for the next FP number changes by a small amount in the right most digits.

```
printf("FLT_MIN  %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, FLT_MIN);
printf("FLT_MIN+ %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, nextafterf(FLT_MIN, 1.0));
printf("one      %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, 1.0);
printf("one+     %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, nextafterf(1.0, 2.0));
printf("FLT_MIN- %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, nextafterf(FLT_MAX, 1.0));
printf("FLT_MAX  %.*e\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG - 1, FLT_MAX);
```

Output

```
FLT_MIN  1.17549435e-38
FLT_MIN+ 1.17549449e-38

one      1.00000000e+00
one+     1.00000012e+00

FLT_MAX- 3.40282326e+38
FLT_MAX  3.40282347e+38
```

The difference between two successive FP number is often called the unit-(in-the)-last-place [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).  It is this difference, as compared to the number that is the "precision".  This difference for [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is constant for every power of 2, then it doubles with increasing power-of-2.

Note the difference of consecutive `float` numbers just above 1.0 is 2<sup>-23</sup>  or 1.0/8,388,608 or `0.000000119...`.  This is the definition of `FLT_EPSILON`.  Some consider that the "precision".  C specifies that the *most* this can be is `1E-5` or 1 part in 100,000.

C does not specify the `float` behave exactly like the commonly employed [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), so expect some variations.

Comment: As a more concrete example, the closest representation of the value *100/3* in `float` is `33.33333206...`. As you can see, only the 7 most significant decimal digits are meaningful. Note that depending on your definition of *precision*, `float` can have either 6 or 7 decimal digits of precision. [This page](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/) has a pretty good write-up on the details.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, floating point numbers use exponents to represent the numbers, not 2's compliment like integers.  user3386109's links explain it, but [here is a link to an interactive app](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to let you see how each bit affects the final result.  I think you playing around with that will help more than an explanation or link to a Wikipedia page ever will.

Answer (score 0):

Computer store floating values using scientific notation.
If the floating point value is 293.990933 then the scientific notation is 0.293990933 * 10^3

> *Here 0 sign bit*
>
> ***293990933 is called mantisa***
>
> 3 is called exponent

Reserved: for sign bit 1 binary digit.
For mantisa, it can have 24 bits and the rest of 32 will be for exponent!

When you use %f it return 6 fraction of the number, by default!