# Default Precision of double in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, double, c++14

I have been learning CPP lately, and I came across this question:

Consider the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Hall
{
 public:
 double cost;
};
int main()
{
 Hall hall;
 hall.cost=10000.50;
 cout<<hall.cost;
 return 0;
}
What will be the output of above coding?
```

The answer to this question is 10000.5, however, I couldn't understand why is it so
? In my opinion, answer should be either 10000.500000 as double has precision upto  6 decimal digits or it should print 10000.50 as it is the value assigned to hall.cost.

Please explain.

Comment: "double has precision upto 6 decimal digits" who the deuce told you that? `10000.5` is one of the few numbers that can be represented exactly as a `double`.

Comment: But why is it that 10000.5 is one of the few numbers that can be represented exactly as a double? @Bathsheba

Comment: What is the concept behind it?

Comment: "10000.5 is one of the few numbers that can be represented exactly as a double" --> there are about 2^64 such values.  Still a drop in the infinity bucket.

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754. It's remarkably clever.

Comment: `double` represent _exactly_ values in the form of  sign*53-bit integer*2^expo.  expo about +/-1024.

Comment: so @Bathsheba I didn't get your point, what relation does expressing 100000.5 in IEEE-754 form have with precision of double (sorry I am a novice)

Comment: Subject to other limiting factors (such as the number of bits in the type), only dyadic rationals can be represented exactly in floating point. And 10000.5 is a dyadic rational. Actually @chux-ReinstateMonica puts it better with his formula.

Comment: Once you've read the article, you'll realise that you can round trip a 15 significant figure decimal number via a double. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120620/how-are-flt-dig-dbl-dig-and-ldbl-dig-determined-in-c

Comment: On a sidenote, I tried executing this program and got 10000.2 as the answer. Can you explain? @Bathsheba https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/443538

Comment: It's not about the precision of `double`, it's how you print it. `10000.5`, `10000.50` and `10000.50000` are equal and they have the same binary representation, so how should it be printed? `std::cout << ...` will not print unnecessary zeros unless explicitly told to.

Comment: Isn't x in this case a dyadic rational?

Comment: https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/443538 Please explain this @churill

Comment: @giri: On your "explain this", `cout` has a default 6 significant figures for output. Silly old C++!

Comment: So, you agree with 10000.2 or 10000.25 @Bathsheba

Comment: The number is exactly 10000.25 (also a dyadic rational), but the default formatting for std::cout will output 10000.2. The duplicate explains how to widen the output.

Comment: If you need to work with the actual maximum precision of double (in decimal digits), you can use std::numeric_limits ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116)) to programmatically access that value.

Comment: "In my opinion, answer should be either 10000.500000 as double has precision upto 6 decimal digits or it should print 10000.50" .  `double` stores a _value_.  10000.5,  10000.500000, 10000.50 have the same value.  A `double` does not retain information about the precession of the value assigned to it.  A `double` can be thought of as having a fixed 53 _binary_ digits of precision.  That is like about 15-17 significant decimal digits.