# Need more understanding of PHP Float CONSTANTS

Tags: php, variables, constants, double, global

So, I just came across these PHP float Constants: PHP_FLOAT_DIG and PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON, and I don't understand both constants (even after studying the official documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php).

Firstly, for PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON, which refers to the minimum representable number (for instance, x), so that "x + 1.0 != 1.0". Well, considering PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON = 2.2204460492503E-16, if you add this value to 1.0, the result in one decimal place is 1.0. So, this doesn't make sense to me.

Secondly, PHP_FLOAT_DIG is defined as: "Number of decimal digits that can be rounded into a float and back without precision loss". I do not understand this definition. Thanks!

Comment: "if you add this value to 1.0, the result in one decimal place is 1.0" - I'm not certain what that statement actually means. But the purpose of `PHP_FLOAT_EPSILON` is to be used when [comparing floats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3149007/231316)

Comment: I honestly don't understand the goal of `PHP_FLOAT_DIG`, but I think from PHP's side, it is just passing through from C, so maybe [this makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59120620/231316). Here's [the thread](https://externals.io/message/96439) where it was brought into PHP if that helps, too.